# Permlink with anchor working with FF but not with Chrome (Wordpress and browser history manipulation involved)

Tags: jquery, wordpress

The problem:

In a WordPress site, using jQuery, there is a link with an anchor like so:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink(get_page_by_title($page_title)); ?>#<?= $anchorName; ?>">Some text</a>
```

When clicked via Firefox, it works: the url changes and the page scrolls to the anchor.

When clicked via Chrome or Safari it does NOT work: the url changes, no access to the anchor.

The new page has an ajax filter, so it loads the data according to the parameters.

Truth be told, I have no clue what to look for.

Maybe the way the browser history is manipulated? I didn't find an answer here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API.

Some obscure WordPress thing?

The code works, so it must be the way the different browsers work, but... again, no clue where to start.

This is the code I think it's the culprit:

```
(function($) {
  function filterAjax(action, method, data) {
    $.ajax({
      url:action,
      data:data,
      type:method,
      success:function(html){
        $('#response').html(html);
      }
    });
    return false;
  }

  var form = $('#filter');
  history.replaceState({
    action: form.attr("action"),
    method: form.attr("method"),
    data: form.serialize()
  }, '', document.location.origin + document.location.pathname + '?' + form.serialize());

  window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    filterAjax(event.state.action, event.state.method, event.state.data);
  }
})(jQuery);
```

The console displays no error messages.

Everything seems to work fine, except for the fact that Chrome and Safari will ignore the anchor.

Any ideas pointing me towards the right direction will be appreciated. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The permalink structure in wordpress causes a redirect by the server.  My first guess would be that the offending browsers aren't passing the # through on the redirect.

First thing to try would be putting a slash in front of the hash

`<a href="<?php echo get_permalink(get_page_by_title($page_title)); ?>/#<?= $anchorName; ?>">Some text</a>`

That might work, depending on how your permalinks are configured - if they have a trailing slash, like `/%postname%/`